# Acumatica - MoveNext error, creating buttons for reports on Kit Assembly screen

Tags: customization, acumatica

I thought that a previous question I had listed was working fine, until I noticed that I needed the InventoryCD not the InventoryID. The inventoryCD is not found on the KitAssembly screen (IN307000) or DAC. So, I have created a new Usr field called UsrInventoryCD and it pulls the same InventoryCD when the KitAssemblyID field is populated. This is working correctly. Next I want to take this field and pass the value into report parameters from a button. This is what I have so far:

```
protected void INKitRegister_UsrInventoryCD_FieldSelecting(PXCache cache, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (INKitRegister)e.Row;
            if (item == null) return;
            var invitem = (InventoryItem)PXSelect<InventoryItem,
            Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<INKitRegister.kitInventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, item.InventoryID);
            if (invitem != null)
            {
                e.ReturnValue = invitem.InventoryCD;
            }
        }

public class KitAssemblyEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<KitAssemblyEntry>
  {
  public override void Initialize()
    {
        Report.AddMenuAction(Report1);
        Report.AddMenuAction(Report2);
        Report.AddMenuAction(Report3);
        Report.AddMenuAction(Report5);
        Report.AddMenuAction(Report6);
        Report.MenuAutoOpen = true;
    }

    #region Event Handlers

    public PXAction<INKitRegister> Report;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Go To", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    protected void report()
    { }

    public PXAction<INKitRegister> Report1;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Report1", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXLookupButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable report1(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      INKitRegister item = Base.Document.Current;
  var style = item.GetExtension<INKitRegisterExt>().UsrInventoryCD;
  INKitRegister doc = Base.Document.Current;
        if (doc != null)
        {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters["ItemNumber"] = style.ToString();
        throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "IN610002", "Report1");
        }
     return adapter.Get();
    }

      public PXAction<INKitRegister> Report2;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Report2", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXLookupButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable report2(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      INKitRegister item = Base.Document.Current;
  var style = item.GetExtension<INKitRegisterExt>().UsrInventoryCD;
  INKitRegister doc = Base.Document.Current;
        if (doc != null)
        {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters["ItemNumber"] = style.ToString();
        throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "IN610003", "Report2");
        }
     return adapter.Get();
    }


      public PXAction<INKitRegister> Report3;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Report3", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXLookupButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable report3(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      INKitRegister item = Base.Document.Current;
  var style = item.GetExtension<INKitRegisterExt>().UsrInventoryCD;
  INKitRegister doc = Base.Document.Current;
        if (doc != null)
        {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters["ItemNumber"] = style.ToString();
        throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "IN610001", "Report3");
        }
     return adapter.Get();
    }

      public PXAction<INKitRegister> Report4;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Report4", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXLookupButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable report4(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      INKitRegister item = Base.Document.Current;
  var style = item.GetExtension<INKitRegisterExt>().UsrInventoryCD;
  INKitRegister doc = Base.Document.Current;
        if (doc != null)
        {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters["ItemNumber"] = style.ToString();
        throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "IN610005", "Report4");
        }
     return adapter.Get();
    }

      public PXAction<INKitRegister> Report5;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Report5", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXLookupButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable report5(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      INKitRegister item = Base.Document.Current;
  var style = item.GetExtension<INKitRegisterExt>().UsrInventoryCD;
  INKitRegister doc = Base.Document.Current;
        if (doc != null)
        {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters["ItemNumber"] = style.ToString();
        throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "IN610006", "Report5");
        }
     return adapter.Get();
    }
    #endregion

  }
```

It compiles just fine but I am getting this error when trying to click on one of the report buttons that have been added to the screen.

```
An unhandled exception has occurred in the function 'MoveNext'. Please see the trace log for more details.
```

And this is the trace log:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred in the function 'MoveNext'. Please see the trace log for more details. 

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
   at PX.Objects.IN.KitAssemblyEntry_Extension.report1(PXAdapter adapter) 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.a(PXAdapter A_0) 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.tryExecutePendingCommand(String viewName, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, Object[] searches, Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, Boolean& closeWindowRequired, Int32& adapterStartRow, Int32& adapterTotalRows) 
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)
```

Here is the previous question I have asked if that pertains any information that might be useful: [Acumatica - Add Reports dropdown to Kit Assembly Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49519132/acumatica-add-reports-dropdown-to-kit-assembly-screen)

Comment: I have changed the code above to fit a better DAC extension pull that I found in some documentation. I am still getting the same error however and I don't know what I'm missing, I do know that this normally happens when it wants to return null or it is not found. This is not being pulled from the database itself, I mean it can be if save is hit, but it does not make a difference. I still get the same error either way.

Answer (score 0):

I went a different direction fix this one but just using a PXSelect instead of a custom field. I deleted the custom field and used the code below. The answer is as follows and working:

```
public class KitAssemblyEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<KitAssemblyEntry>
  {
  public override void Initialize()
    {
        Report.AddMenuAction(Report1);
        Report.AddMenuAction(Report2);
        Report.AddMenuAction(Report3);
        Report.AddMenuAction(Report5);
        Report.AddMenuAction(Report6);
        Report.MenuAutoOpen = true;
    }

    #region Event Handlers

    public PXAction<INKitRegister> Report;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Go To", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    protected void report()
    { }

    public PXAction<INKitRegister> Report1;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Report1", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXLookupButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable report1(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      INKitRegister item = Base.Document.Current;
      var invitem = (InventoryItem)PXSelect<InventoryItem,
            Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<INKitRegister.kitInventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, item.InventoryID);
      INKitRegister doc = Base.Document.Current;
        if (doc != null)
        {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters["ItemNumber"] = invitem.InventoryCD.ToString();
        throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "IN610002", "Report1");
        }
     return adapter.Get();
    }

      public PXAction<INKitRegister> Report2;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Report2", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXLookupButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable report2(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      INKitRegister item = Base.Document.Current;
      var invitem = (InventoryItem)PXSelect<InventoryItem,
            Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<INKitRegister.kitInventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, item.InventoryID);
      INKitRegister doc = Base.Document.Current;
        if (doc != null)
        {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters["ItemNumber"] = invitem.InventoryCD.ToString();
        throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "IN610003", "Report2");
        }
     return adapter.Get();
    }


      public PXAction<INKitRegister> Report3;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Report3", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXLookupButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable report3(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      INKitRegister item = Base.Document.Current;
      var invitem = (InventoryItem)PXSelect<InventoryItem,
            Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<INKitRegister.kitInventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, item.InventoryID);
      INKitRegister doc = Base.Document.Current;
        if (doc != null)
        {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters["ItemNumber"] = invitem.InventoryCD.ToString();
        throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "IN610001", "Report3");
        }
     return adapter.Get();
    }

      public PXAction<INKitRegister> Report4;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Report4", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXLookupButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable report4(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      INKitRegister item = Base.Document.Current;
      var invitem = (InventoryItem)PXSelect<InventoryItem,
            Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<INKitRegister.kitInventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, item.InventoryID);
      INKitRegister doc = Base.Document.Current;
        if (doc != null)
        {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters["ItemNumber"] = invitem.InventoryCD.ToString();
        throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "IN610005", "Report4");
        }
     return adapter.Get();
    }

      public PXAction<INKitRegister> Report5;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Report5", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXLookupButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable report5(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      INKitRegister item = Base.Document.Current;
      var invitem = (InventoryItem)PXSelect<InventoryItem,
            Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<INKitRegister.kitInventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, item.InventoryID);
      INKitRegister doc = Base.Document.Current;
        if (doc != null)
        {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters["ItemNumber"] = invitem.InventoryCD.ToString();
        throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "IN610006", "Report5");
        }
     return adapter.Get();
    }
    #endregion

  }
```